# Why does pressing the button only work 2 times? when the screen is narrowed to less than 768px

Tags: javascript, html, css

why does pressing the button only work 2 times? when the screen is narrowed to less than 768px
I need to make it infinite
CODEPEN - https://codepen.io/dxxxxxxfly/pen/LYmgwGo

```js
let overleft = 0;

const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const nav = document.querySelector('.main_nav > ul').cloneNode(1);

burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (overlay.style.left < 500) {
    overlay.style.left = overleft + 'px';
    render();
  } else {
    overlay.style.left = -500 + 'px';
  }

  function render() {
    overlay.appendChild(nav);
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Inter';
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.learn_more {
  background-color: #111131;
}

.learn_more>p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ABABFA;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  font-size: 0.8125em;
}

nav {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  padding: 22px 36px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.main_nav {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul>li {
  padding-left: 24px;
}

ul>li>a {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  color: #413E52;
}

.other_nav {
  display: flex;
}

.burger {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #5b64fb;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.overlay {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: #a1a1cb;
  display: none;
  left: -500px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.9s;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .other_nav,
  .main_nav>ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
  .overlay {
    display: flex;
    /*left: 0px;*/
    transition: 0.9s;
  }
  .main_nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="learn_more">
      <p>Слушайте музыку в высоком качестве и без рекламы</p>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="main_nav">
        <div class="logo"><img src="assets/img/logosvg.svg" alt="Logo"></div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="index_two.html">Дискография</a></li>
          <li><a href="index_three.html">Альбомы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="other_nav">
        <div class="searth">
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/search.svg" alt=""></a>
          <button class="subscribe">Поиск</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="burger">

      </div>



    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `overlay.style.left` that return a string, at first there is no style for left so it will return null. but next times it has value that its make the `if` always false. So you better to use `overlay.offsetLeft` instead of `overlay.style.left` for the `if`.

The code:

```
if (overlay.offsetLeft < 0) {
    overlay.style.left = overleft + 'px';
    render();
} else {
overlay.style.left = -500 + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works only two times because `overlay.style.left` returns string like that `-500px` and it's not `< 500`.  You have to cut out `px` and convert it to number. It also doesn't work on first click because `overlay.style.left`  for first time returns empty string (use `getComputedStyle`). Change burger  function `onclick` to it.

```
burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const cssObj = window.getComputedStyle(overlay, null);
  let left = cssObj.getPropertyValue("left");

  left = Number(left.slice(0,-2));
  
    if (left !== 0) {
       overlay.style.left = "0px";
       render();
    } else {
       overlay.style.left = "-500px";
    }

    function render() {
        overlay.appendChild(nav);
    }
    
});
```

```js
let overleft = 0;

const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const nav = document.querySelector('.main_nav > ul').cloneNode(1);

burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const cssObj = window.getComputedStyle(overlay, null);
  let left = cssObj.getPropertyValue("left");
  
  left = Number(left.slice(0,-2));
  
    if (left !== 0) {
         overlay.style.left = "0px";
         render();
    } else {
       overlay.style.left = "-500px";
    }

    function render() {
        overlay.appendChild(nav);
    }
    
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Inter';
}

.content {
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.learn_more {
    background-color: #111131;
}

.learn_more > p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ABABFA;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    font-size: 0.8125em;
}

nav {
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
}


.nav {
    padding: 22px 36px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.main_nav {
    display: flex;
}

ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-left: 36px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

li {

    list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li {
    padding-left: 24px;
}

ul>li>a {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    color: #413E52;
}

.other_nav {
    display: flex;
}

.burger {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #5b64fb;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.overlay {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vw;
    background: #a1a1cb;
    display: none;
    left: -500px;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.9s;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .other_nav, .main_nav > ul {
        display: none;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
    .overlay {
        display: flex;
        /*left: 0px;*/
         transition: 0.9s;
    }

    .main_nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="learn_more">
                <p>Слушайте музыку в высоком качестве и без рекламы</p>
                </div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <div class="main_nav">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="assets/img/logosvg.svg" alt="Logo"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index_two.html">Дискография</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index_three.html">Альбомы</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="other_nav">
                    <div class="searth">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/search.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <button class="subscribe">Поиск</button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="burger">
                        
                </div>
                
                    
                
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>
```